# Understanding optimal alpha value for LeakyReLU in U-net and insights on mask convolution

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, unet-neural-network

First, let me provide the code:

```py
c1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')
c1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(c1)
```

I am training with the U-net model and have encountered several issues that I couldn't find solutions for online. My questions are related to the use of convolution within the U-net model:

1. I would like to know what the value of this mask is and what value is used for the convolution with this mask.
2. Additionally, I want to know what is the best value to set for the alpha in LeakyReLU. I set it to 0.01 because I saw others using 0.01, but I want to know how to determine the appropriate value for alpha.

I want to understand the value of the mask. I suspect that 0.01 may not be the optimal solution for my model. However, I would like to know if there is any theoretical basis to support whether I should increase or decrease the alpha value.